# geom_linerange: how to overlying two line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, figure

Good morning,

I've to do a plot with confidence intervals for two estimators. I know that exist plotrix::plotCI() but I'd like to know if I can obtain the same result with ggplot2. I try to use geom_linerange() but I'm not able to plot the two intervals, for each group, one near the other. geom_linerange()
overlaps the two lines.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried and some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by overlaps them? If they have different ymin and ymax, when I have used the function, it has plotted them separately.

Alternatively, you could consider making your own line segments to plot the same thing with geom_segment(). It's more effort but may give you more flexibility.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).